# Why does this code go into infinite loop

Tags: c, long-integer

This function below checks to see if an integer is prime or not.

I'm running a for loop from 3 to 2147483647 (+ve limit of long int).

But this code hangs, can't find out why?

```
#include<time.h>
#include<stdio.h>
int isPrime1(long t)
{
    long i;
    if(t==1) return 0;
    if(t%2==0) return 0;
    for(i=3;i<t/2;i+=2)
    {
        if(t%i==0) return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}
int main()
{
    long i=0;
    time_t s,e;

    s = time(NULL);
    for(i=3; i<2147483647; i++)
    {
        isPrime1(i);
    }
    e = time(NULL);
    printf("\n\t Time : %ld secs", e - s );
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure it really hangs and it's not that it just takes a very long time to execute?

Comment: Are you sure it is actually stuck in a loop and not just REALLY long to execute?

Comment: I don't think it's an infinite loop. You simply have more than 2147483647 loop, that's all. Way too heavy

Comment: Maybe thats just to much for your computer, have you tried with a less bigger number like `for(i=3; i<100; i++)` ?

Comment: the complexity of this thing looks n^2 to me, so 2147483647 might be pushing it.

Comment: So it's just code that is taking too long to complete. Sorry guys must have thought before posting question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It will eventually terminate, but will take a while, if you look at your loops when you inline your `isPrime1` function, you have something like:

```
for(i=3; i<2147483647; i++)
   for(j=3;j<i/2;j+=2)
```

which is roughly n*n/4 = O(n^2). Your loop trip count is way too high.

Answer (score 2):

It depends upon the system and the compiler. On Linux, with GCC 4.7.2 and compiling with `gcc -O2 vishaid.c -o vishaid` the program returns immediately, and the compiler is optimizing all the call to `isPrime1` by removing them (I checked the generated assembler code with `gcc -O2 -S -fverbose-asm`, then `main` does not even call `isPrime1`). And GCC is right: since `isPrime1` has no side-effect and its result is not used, its call can be removed. Then the `for` loop has an empty body, so can also be optimized.

<sup>The lesson to learn is that when benchmarking optimized binaries, you better have some real side-effect in your code.</sup>

Also, arithmetic tells us that some `i` is prime if it has no divisors less than its square root. So better code:

```
int isPrime1(long t) {
  long i;
  double r = sqrt((double)t);
  long m = (long)r;
  if(t==1) return 0;
  if(t%2==0) return 0;
  for(i=3;i <= m;i +=2)
    if(t%i==0) return 0;
  return 1; 
}
```

On my system (x86-64/Debian/Sid with i7 3770K Intel processor, the core running that program is at 3.5GHz) `long`-s are 64 bits. So I coded

```
int main ()
{
  long i = 0;
  long cnt = 0;
  time_t s, e;

  s = time (NULL);
  for (i = 3; i < 2147483647; i++)
    {
      if (isPrime1 (i) && (++cnt % 4096) == 0) {
        printf ("#%ld: %ld\n", cnt, i);
        fflush (NULL);
      }
    }
  e = time (NULL);
  printf ("\n\t Time : %ld secs\n", e - s);
  return 0;
}
```

and after about 4 minutes it was still printing a lot of lines, including

```
#6819840: 119566439
#6823936: 119642749
#6828032: 119719177
#6832128: 119795597
```

I'm guessing it would need several hours to complete. After 30 minutes it is still spitting (slowly)

```
#25698304: 486778811
#25702400: 486862511
#25706496: 486944147
#25710592: 487026971
```

Actually, the program needed 4 hours and 16 minutes to complete. Last outputs are

```
#105086976: 2147139749
#105091072: 2147227463
#105095168: 2147315671
#105099264: 2147402489

   Time : 15387 secs
```

---

BTW, this program is still really inefficient: The `primes` program `/usr/games/primes` from `bsdgames` package is answering much quicker

```
% time /usr/games/primes 1 2147483647 | tail
2147483423
2147483477
2147483489
2147483497
2147483543
2147483549
2147483563
2147483579
2147483587
2147483629
/usr/games/primes 1 2147483647 
     10.96s user 0.26s system 99% cpu 11.257 total
```

and it has still printed 105097564 lines (most being skipped by `tail`)

If you are interested in prime number generation, read several math books (it is still a research subject if you are interested in efficiency; you still can get your PhD on that subject.). Start with the [sieve of erasthothenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) and [primality test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test) pages on Wikipedia.

Most importantly, **compile first your program with debugging information and all warnings** (i.e. `gcc -Wall -g` on Linux) and learn to **use your debugger** (i.e. `gdb` on Linux). You could then interrupt your debugged program (with `Ctrl-C` under `gdb`, then let it continue with the `cont` command to `gdb`) after about a minute and two, then observe that the `i` counter in main is increasing slowly. Perhaps also ask for profiling information (with `-pg` option to `gcc` then use `gprof`). And when coding complex arithmetic things it is well worth to read good math books about them (and primality test is a very complex subject, central to most cryptographic algorithms).

Comment: This is only happening because he is not doing anything with the return value in this case, since it is a minimal example. For a real program he is probably interested in the return value ;)

Comment: I know that, but I wanted to attract the original poster to some interesting point about optimization and benchmarking.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very inefficient approach to test for primes, and that's why it seems to hang.
Search the web for more efficient algorithms, such as the Sieve of Eratosthenes

Answer (score 0):

Here try this, see if it's really an infinite loop

```
int main()
{
    long i=0;
    time_t s,e;

    s = time(NULL);
    for(i=3; i<2147483647; i++)
    {
        isPrime1(i);

        //calculate the time execution for each loop
        e = time(NULL);
        printf("\n\t Time for loop %d: %ld secs", i, e - s );
    }

    return 0;
}
```